# option_page_capability_ not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm desperate, i tried searching east and west for a solution, but i can't seem to find it.
The problem is I tried to make a plugin in wordpress that registers some simple settings.
Here's the code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_media' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
    add_menu_page( 'Menù della settimana', 'Menù della settimana', 'administrator', 'settimana', 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page');
}

function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'image_url' );
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'date' );
}

function goddamit() {
    return 'edit_posts';
}

add_filter( 'option_page_capability_settimana', 'goddamit' );

function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() {   ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Menù della settimana</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <div>
                        <label for="image_url">Carica pdf</label>
                        <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo  esc_attr( get_option('image_url') ) ?>">
                        <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Carica pdf">
                    </div>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <div>
                        <label for="date">Date (inserire 'dal x al y di mese')</label>
                        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('date') ); ?>" />
                    <div>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

So far so good, if the user is an admin there are no problems, if the user an editor you get the damn error 'Cheatin' uh?'.
What am i doing wrong?

Everyone is suggesting that the function `option_page_capability_` should have the slug of the page, it does, it still doesn't work. Help.

Answer (score 2):

Has been some years, but i had the same problem today.

I resolved it by using the name of the group settings instead of the slug of the menu page.

```
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_yourgroupsettingsname', 'yourfunction' );
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you include example from the ops question above please... `option_page_capability_yourgroupsettingsname` would be what exactly? 
Would it be `option_page_capability_my_cool_plugin_settings` or `option_page_capability_my_cool_plugin_settings-group`? I am asking because I can not get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

What else do you expect by setting capability to `administrator` in `add_menu_page` call?

```
add_menu_page( 'Menù della settimana', 'Menù della settimana', 'administrator', 'settimana', 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page');
```

Set it to `edit_posts`

```
add_menu_page( 'Menù della settimana', 'Menù della settimana', 'edit_posts', 'settimana', 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page');
```

And remove that weird filter.